# Human readable boost::stacktrace::safe_dump output

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-stacktrace

I'm trying to set up a stacktrace logging signal handler using boost::stacktrace. The Boost documentation suggests:

```
#include <signal.h>     // ::signal, ::raise
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

void my_signal_handler(int signum) {
    ::signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
    boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to("./backtrace.dump");
    ::raise(SIGABRT);
}
```

However, the output from this file is a binary format which the docs don't seem to mention how to read, except for using `boost::stacktrace::from_dump`. One alternative I found from another SO answer(and the [function documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/stacktrace/safe_dump_to.hpp)) was to use `od -tx8 -An <dumpfile>`, but the output of this still seems to not be human readable. [Coliru Snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/330232f827be8cf3)

Is there a way to read this file using standard linux tools?